# Copy Worksheet to a New WorkBook in VbScript - "the object invoked is disconnected from its clients" error code: 80010108

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, scripting

I'm new to VbScript. I'm trying to copy all the worksheets in a folder to a single workbook. It is getting copied  but it is showing an error before saving the new workbook. error:**"the object invoked is disconnected from its clients"**. code: **80010108**. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit  
'On Error Resume Next

Dim strFileName, strDirectory, counter, extension, Temp
Dim intMessage, FileName, wbSrc, wbDst
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objExcel, objWorkbook

'create an empty excel file starts

strFileName = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\LD.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

objExcel.Quit

'created an empty excel file



'file extension to look for
extension = "xlsx"  

'directory to look in
'strDirectory = InputBox("Enter the Folder Path:","Folder Path")  
strDirectory = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\Excel Merger Project"
counter = 0  

'File Objects Initialization

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)  

counter = 0

set wbDst = objExcel.workbooks.open(strFileName)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files  
    if LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) then  
        counter = counter + 1 
        'Get the file name  
        FileName = objFile.Name
        FileName = strDirectory & "\" & FileName
        msgbox(FileName)
        set wbSrc = objExcel.workbooks.open(FileName)
        wbSrc.sheets(wbSrc.Sheets(1).Name).copy wbDst.sheets(counter)
    end if
Next

objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the new object now is `wbDst` and not `objWorkbook`

The object `objWorkbook` was already destroyed. You declared a new object `wbDst` in this line

```
set wbDst = objExcel.workbooks.open(strFileName)
```

So simply change the line

```
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
```

to

```
wbDst.Save
```

You don't need a `.SaveAs` again

Ideally, you don't need to quit and close excel. You can keep the file open and instead of using `wbDst`, use `objWorkbook`

**EDIT**

Your code can be re-written as (UNTESTED).

**Note**: You need to close `wbSrc` as well else you will have lot of files open.

```
Dim strFileName, strDirectory, counter, extension, Temp
Dim intMessage, FileName, wbSrc
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objExcel, objWorkbook

strFileName = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\LD.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs (strFileName)

extension = "xlsx"

strDirectory = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\Excel Merger Project"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

counter = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) Then
        counter = counter + 1
        FileName = objFile.Name
        FileName = strDirectory & "\" & FileName
        Set wbSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        wbSrc.Sheets(1).Copy objWorkbook.Sheets(counter)
        wbSrc.Close
    End If
Next

'~~> Close and Cleanup   
objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set wbSrc = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

BTW, your code can be further fine tuned. For example, you do not require the `Counter` variable.

**FINAL EDIT**

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
'~~> Change Paths as applicable
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, wbSrc
Dim strFileName, strDirectory, extension, Filename
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile

strFileName = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\LD.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

extension = "xlsx"

strDirectory = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Excel Merger Project"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) Then
        Filename = objFile.Name
        Filename = strDirectory & "\" & Filename
        Set wbSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
        wbSrc.Sheets(1).Copy objWorkbook.Sheets(objWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        wbSrc.Close
    End If
Next

'~~> Close and Cleanup
objWorkbook.SaveAs (strFileName)
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set wbSrc = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help in my second project too :) You are awesome....

Answer (score 0):

#### Try to comment this line in the middle of your script:

```
'objExcel.Quit

'created an empty excel file
```

When you call objExcel.Quit, no Excel instance is on life. So you can no more do this after:

```
set wbDst = objExcel.workbooks.open(strFileName)
```

As here objExcel is dead - disconnected from Excel.Application.

#### Please copy and paste this full code for testing:

```
Option Explicit  
'On Error Resume Next

Dim strFileName, strDirectory, counter, extension, Temp
Dim intMessage, FileName, wbSrc, wbDst
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objExcel, objWorkbook

'create an empty excel file starts

strFileName = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\LD.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

'objExcel.Quit

'created an empty excel file



'file extension to look for
extension = "xlsx"  

'directory to look in
'strDirectory = InputBox("Enter the Folder Path:","Folder Path")  
strDirectory = "C:\Users\ARUN\Desktop\Excel Merger Project"
counter = 0  

'File Objects Initialization

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)  

counter = 0

set wbDst = objExcel.workbooks.open(strFileName)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files  
    if LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) then  
        counter = counter + 1 
        'Get the file name  
        FileName = objFile.Name
        FileName = strDirectory & "\" & FileName
        msgbox(FileName)
        set wbSrc = objExcel.workbooks.open(FileName)
        wbSrc.sheets(wbSrc.Sheets(1).Name).copy wbDst.sheets(counter)
    end if
Next

objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objExcel.Quit
```