# VBS - How to copy worksheet from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, copy, worksheet

I am trying to copy a .csv into a new worksheet in existing workbook. I have replicated code from documentation and from similar questions but I am getting
`Expected Statement 800A0400` error.

```
    Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
    Set wb_report = xl.Workbooks.Open("path.xlsm")
    Set old_raw_ws = wb_report.Sheets("Raw Export")
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    old_raw_ws.Delete
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Const vbFormatStandard = 1
    Const vbFormatText     = 2
    Const vbFormatDate     = 4
    
    Const xlDelimited      = 1
    Const xlDoubleQuote    = 1
    
    ' change according to number/type of the fields in your CSV
    dataTypes = Array( Array(1, vbFormatText) _
      , Array(2, vbFormatStandard) _
      , Array(3, vbFormatText) _
      , Array(4, vbFormatDate) _
      )
    
    xl.Workbooks.OpenText "path2.csv", , , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False, False, True, , , , dataTypes
    Set wb_source = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    wb_source.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wb_report.Sheets(1) ' this line generates the error
    
    WScript.Sleep(5000)
    wb_report.Close
    wb_source.Close
    xl.Quit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Worksheet to a New WorkBook in VbScript - "the object invoked is disconnected from its clients" error code: 80010108](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275545/copy-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook-in-vbscript-the-object-invoked-is-disconnect)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy set of worksheets to another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841073)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.vbs (script) for copying a whole sheet from a file to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43461716)